# css files in webroot in cakephp and linking with html

Tags: php, css, cakephp

I need a simple help with cakephp. It may be a problem regarding routes but I couldn't figure out how to solve this problem.

I've put all my css files in webroot/css in my app. In my default layout, I just put a html link `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` . It works with my url `localhost/items (index function)`, but it doesn't work when I do `localhost/items/view/2 (view function)`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the HtmlHelper to generate links to assets in webroot as shown in [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3acss).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the HTML Helper like :

```
echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');
```

Comment: and if my assets files are inside webroot/assets/ ? how can I access them

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->Html->css('/assets/css/bootstrap.min');
```